# Why mounted hook fires even if el is not exists in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple vue instance:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#myEl",
    data: {
        parent: null,
        posts: [],
        total: 0,
        currentPage: 0
    },
    mounted: function () {
        alert("mounted");
    }
});
```

Evething is fine, when `#myEl` is exist on the page, but if it not, mounter hook fires anyway.

But why? There is no element to mount instance for, so why it mounted anyway?
What should I do in vue-way to check the `el` existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/52719ccab8fccffbdf497b96d3731dc86f04c1ce/src/platforms/web/util/index.js#L19), if the element is not found then a warning is issued and a `<div>` is created instead.

It is your responsibility to check if the element exists or not ([`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)) prior to instantiating the component.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect so weird behavior! Do you have any idea why vue do it like that?

Comment: @YesMan Vue renders to the DOM [asynchronously](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue).

Answer (score 2):

[From Evan You](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4486)

> When el is not available, the component mounts in memory (similar to
>   calling $mount() without arguments).
>
> There are warnings in the console telling you that the target el
>   cannot be found.

If you don't want this to happen, wrap the instance in a check for the element e.g.

`if(document.querySelector('#el')){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it, though it may not be the vue-way, is just to query the element before trying to mount the instance. It would look something like:

```
const element = document.querySelector("#myEl");

if (element) {
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: element,
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but, unfortunately, that is not vue-way :(